# How to take data from webapi using angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

**TestTime.ts:**

```
export class TestTime {
    id: number;
    taskRepositoryID: any;
    timesheetID: any;
    timeCategoryID: any;
    startTime: string;
    endTime: string;
    duration: any;
    comment: string;
}
```

testTime.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TestTime } from './TestTime';
import { HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

 @Injectable()
export class TestTimeService {
public values: any;
constructor(public _http: HttpClient) { }
private _timeTestURL = 'http://localhost:3186/myData;

getTimes() {
    return this._http.get<TestTime>(this._timeTestURL);
}

public getAll<TestTime>(): Observable<TestTime> {
    return this._http.get<TestTime>(this._timeTestURL);
}
}
```

testTime.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestTime } from './TestTime';
import { TestTimeService } from './testTime.service';



@Component({
selector: 'app-testTime-component',
template: `
 <h1> Test Time </h1>
   <ul>
<li ngFor="let time of times">
 <span> {{time}} </span>
</li>
 </ul>
`
})


 export class TimeTestComponent {

constructor(private _timeServcie: TestTimeService) { }

errorMessage: string;
public times: TestTime[];
public TimeSheetData: string;
ngOnInit() {


    this._timeServcie
        .getAll<TestTime[]>()
        .subscribe((data: TestTime[]) => this.times = data,
        error => (ex) => {
            console.log("error" + ex);
        },
        () => {
            console.log("error error"); 
        });
}

 }
```

Above you can see my code. I can't figure out why I am not getting the data.
After the "**Test Time**" which is in the template of **timeTest.component.ts**, there is nothing which means I am not even taken correctly the data, cuz if I was taking it correctly at least there should have been the **.** from the list items

Comment: could you elaborate which error are you receiving?

Comment: @AliTurabAbbasi, I have marked it in the code.  testTime.component.ts last console.log I have added //Here ,

Comment: this does not mean that there is an error. the () => {} part executes at the end no matter if there was an error or not. If there was an error then console.log("error" + ex); would have printed

Comment: what u are getting this line console.log("error" + ex);

Comment: @ShanmugapriyaD, nothing, it's passing

Comment: can't find the reason why it's not taking the data, no errors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you casting the http.get()methods, what you should do instead is to define the return type of the methods and then you will be able to see error more clearly. try this

```
getTimes(): Observable<TestTime> {
    return this._http.get(this._timeTestURL);
}

public getAll(): Observable<TestTime[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._timeTestURL);
}
```

and then your observer in component should be like

```
this._timeServcie.getAll().subscribe(
        (data: TestTime[]) => this.times = data,
        error => (ex) => {
            console.log("error" + ex);
        },
        () => {
            console.log("completed"); //THIS ISN'T ERROR
        });
```